# check and update column based on multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe df where there are 3 columns

```
id code  status   
1  US    Y      
2  IN    Y
3  UK    Y
4  CN    Y
5  KR    Y
```

I want to update column status to **N** where `code not in ("US", "UK")`

I tried using this but failed

```
df.loc[df['code'] not in ("US","UK"),["status"]] ='N'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: How do I assign values based on multiple conditions for existing columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631841/pandas-how-do-i-assign-values-based-on-multiple-conditions-for-existing-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
df['status'] = np.where(df['code'].isin(["US","UK"]), df['status'], 'N')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['status'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'N' if x[1] not in ['US','UK'] else x[2],axis=1)
```