# How to set condition for 2 index in PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

```
type     name     balance                                         
Assets   John     4.000         
Debt     John     0.359   
Assets   Anna     1.5
Debt     Anna     8
Assets   Bob      3.2
Debt     Jim      5
```

code

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['info']).set_index(['type','name'])

return df.loc[df.balance > 2]
```

out put

```
                 balance 
type     name                                                     
Assets   John     4.000
Debt     Anna     8   
Assets   Bob      3.2
Debt     Jim      5
```

i want out put like this if assets over 2

```
                 balance 
type     name                                                     
Assets   John     4.000   
Assets   Bob      3.2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: How do I assign values based on multiple conditions for existing columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631841/pandas-how-do-i-assign-values-based-on-multiple-conditions-for-existing-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `df.filter` along it's index `0` then chain `.loc`

```
df.filter(like='Assets',axis=0).loc[df.balance > 2]

             balance
type   name         
Assets John      4.0
       Bob       3.2
```

you can also use `isin` and specify the level.

```
df[(df.index.isin(['Assets'],level=0)) & (df.balance > 2)]


             balance
type   name         
Assets John      4.0
       Bob       3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two conditions to first filter by column type and then by balance

```
df = df[df["type"] == "Assets"].loc[df["balance"] > 2]
```

Output:

```
    type    name    balance
0   Assets  John    4.0
4   Assets  Bob     3.2
```