# error in creating seaborne graph in Jupyter by using if else

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, jupyter

I've tried to create a graph for the dates column in python with seaborn. I'm getting the error bellow. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

----> 4 if df['MS_Date']=="s.xii" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xii(1)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xii(2)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xii(in)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xii(ex)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xii(med)":
5         df['MS_Date']== "12th century"
6 if df['MS_Date']=="s.xii/xiii" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xii/xiii":

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in **nonzero**(self)
1477
1478         By ambiguous, we mean that it matches both a level of the input
-> 1479         `axis` and a label of the other axis.
1480
1481         Parameters

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

The code:

```
if df['MS_Date']=="s.xii" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xii(1)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xii(2)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xii(in)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xii(ex)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xii(med)": 
        df['MS_Date']== "12th century"
if df['MS_Date']=="s.xii/xiii" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xii/xiii":
    df['MS_Date']=="12 & 13 century"
if df['MS_Date']=="s.xiii" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xiii(1)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xiii(2)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xiii(in)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xiii(ex)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xiii(med)":
    df['MS_Date']=="13 century"
if df['MS_Date']=="s.xiii/s.xiv" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xiii/xiv":
    df['MS_Date']=="13 & 14 century"
if df['MS_Date']=="s.xiii/s.xv":
    df['MS_Date']=="13 & 15 century"
if  df['MS_Date']=="s.xiv" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xiv(1)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xiv(2)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xiv(in)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xiv(ex)"  or df['MS_Date']=="s.xiv(med)": 
    df['MS_Date']=="14th century"
if  df['MS_Date']=="s.xiv/xv":
    df['MS_Date']== "14 & 15 century"
if df['MS_Date']=="s.xv" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xv(1)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xv(2)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xv(in)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xv(ex)" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xv(med)" :
    df['MS_Date']=="15th century"
if  df['MS_Date']=="s.xv/xvi":
    df['MS_Date']== "15 & 16 century"
if df['MS_Date']=="xvi" or df['MS_Date']=="s.xvi(in)":
    df['MS_Date']== "16 century"
else:
    df['MS_Date']=="unknown"



import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(25, 12)
sns.countplot(x='MS_Date', data=df, order=df['MS_Date'].value_counts().index, palette="Greens_d")
sns.set(style="white")
dfnew=nbl.describe(include=['object'])
num=dfnew.loc['count','MS_Date']
# df.iloc[0]['MS_Date']
ax.set_title('Distrubution of all manuscripts '+str(num)+' manuscripts')
```

Comment: Better use `np.select` method. Will be easier for you to keep the track of conditions and value to be assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

This error means you are getting a series of boolean values in place of a single boolean value. For using if and alse you need a single `True/False` value but here by using `df['MS_Date']=="s.xii"` you are getting a series which will give you all the locations with `True/False` based on criteria they meet.

**sample df:**

```
    Player      Position    color
0   Pele        Forward     black
1   Platini     Midfielder  white
2   Beckenbauer Defender    red
```

---

If I want to change the value of color column based on some criteria then instead of using if and else I will write this as like this:

```
df.loc[(df['Player']=='Pele') | (df['Position']=='Forward'), 'color'] = 'white'
```

Or

You can write it like this using `numpy.where`:

```
np.where(<condition>, <value1 if true>, <value2 if false>)
```

---

```
df['color'] = np.where((df['Player']=='Pele') | (df['Position']=='Forward'), 'black', df.color)
```

---

To make it clean and concise use `np.select` see here how to use:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60244752/6660373

and also instead of using `==` you can use `eq`

I will use loc to get the location where my condition holds true. and on that position I will choose a column to change. `df.loc[<conditions>, <column to assign>] = <value>`

Use like this:

```
df.loc[(df['MS_Date']=="s.xii") | (df['MS_Date']=="s.xii(1)") | (df['MS_Date']=="s.xii(2)") | (df['MS_Date']=="s.xii(in)") | (df['MS_Date']=="s.xii(ex)") | (df['MS_Date']=="s.xii(med)"), 'MS_Date']= "12th century"
df.loc[(df['MS_Date']=="s.xii/xiii") | (df['MS_Date']=="s.xii/xiii"), 'MS_Date']="12 & 13 century"
```

Comment: Yes! it really helps! I just trying to figure out how to sort

Comment: @ Pygirl do you know how to sort? 12th, 13th, 14th and etc? sns.countplot(x='MS_Date', data=df, order=df['MS_Date'].value_counts().index, palette="Greens_d")

Comment: You have to create a custom.sort function.