# Overwriting column data basis multiple condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Existing Dataframe :

```
Id      last_dt_of_payment      Group     payer_status
A1            22/08/2022          x            1
A2            21/05/2022          x            1
A3            01/09/2022          y            1
A4            22/01/2022          y            1
A5            26/02/2022          p            1
A6            30/09/2022          s            1
```

Expected Dataframe :

```
Id      last_dt_of_payment      Group     payer_status
A1            22/08/2022          x            1
A2            21/05/2022          x            0
A3            01/09/2022          y            1
A4            22/01/2022          y            0
A5            26/02/2022          p            1
A6            30/09/2022          s            1
```

I am trying to Overwrite the **payer_status** basis the **Group** and **last_dt_of_payment**.
if payer_status is **either x or y** `and` the **last_dt_of_payment is done within last 3 months** , the payer_status to be tagged as 1 else 0

stuck with applying logic for checking last three months payment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I assign values based on multiple conditions for existing columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631841/how-do-i-assign-values-based-on-multiple-conditions-for-existing-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

```
groups = ['x','y']

#convert to datetimes
df['last_dt_of_payment'] = pd.to_datetime(df['last_dt_of_payment'], dayfirst=True)

#create testing Period
td = pd.Period('2022-09', freq='m')
#get column to months periods
per = df['last_dt_of_payment'].dt.to_period('m')

#chain both mask
m = df['Group'].isin(groups) & per.lt(td - 3)

#set 0
df.loc[m, 'payer_status'] = 0

print (df)
   Id last_dt_of_payment Group  payer_status
0  A1         2022-08-22     x             1
1  A2         2022-05-21     x             0
2  A3         2022-09-01     y             1
3  A4         2022-01-22     y             0
4  A5         2022-02-26     p             1
5  A6         2022-09-30     s             1
```

Comment: thanks, how does it check for Group since i need this status to be updated  for x and y

Comment: df['Group'].isin(['x','y'])

Comment: thanks. just one doubt when it check for the past three months , it is current month(i.e. Nov2022) - 3month. is my understanding correct.?

Comment: @Roshankumar - No, it is not clear from question. So I use maximal datetime. Solution will be changed

Comment: can we set a month , i mean consider sept 2022 as a threshold and check whether the last date of payment.  i.e. checking past 3month from sept 2022.  this would really solve the purpose

Comment: @Roshankumar - answer was edited.

Comment: kudos..!! one last  can we consider sept 2022 as a threshold and check whether the last date of payment. i.e. checking past 3month from sept 2022.

Comment: @Roshankumar - answer was editd.